# Issue with Custom Transition in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I've been using this code to go a a different view controller.

```
let details = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewMainMurmur")
details?.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
present(details!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And I have created a slideAnimator class to customize my transition

```
class SlideAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    let duration = 0.5

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
     }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from) else {
            return
        }

        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) else {
            return
        }

        let container = transitionContext.containerView

        let screenOffUp = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -container.frame.height)
        let screenOffDown = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: container.frame.height)

        container.addSubview(fromView)
        container.addSubview(toView)

        toView.transform = screenOffUp

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

            fromView.transform = screenOffDown
            fromView.alpha = 0.5
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            toView.alpha = 1

        }) { (success) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(success )
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is that I only know how to use the slideAnimator class when I have a drawn a segue on the storyboard.
How can i use the slideAnimator when i use present() ?

Comment: why not still use segue?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `present`, set the presented view controller's `transitioningDelegate` to your SlideAnimator.

Comment: Thanx, i think thats what im looking for, but still didnt work for me:
let login = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewEvents"); login?.transitioningDelegate = SlideAnimator(); present(login!, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Saying `transitioningDelegate = SlideAnimator()` like that causes an instance to pop into existence and then vanish instantly. That isn't going to do you any good. You need an _existing_ SlideAnimator with _persistence_. It needs to be a _property_ of some persistent instance.